# Setting up network proxy in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I need help, I able to run this code in Python and now I want to change to Robot Framework and it doesn't work.

**Python - works fine **

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "10.x.xx.xx")
options.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 80)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", "10.x.xx.xx")
options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 80)


driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/test")
```

**Then, I want to change to Robot Framework**

```
${firefox_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].FirefoxOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Create Webdriver    Firefox    firefox_options=${firefox_options}   executable_path=C:/Python312/Drivers/geckodriver

Open Browser   ${destinationUrl}    browser=${BROWSER}   options=set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1);set_preference("network.proxy.http", "10.x.xx.xx");set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 80);set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", "10.x.xx.xx");set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 80)
```

**Error:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09pRT.png)

Firefox_options in Python works fine so can someone help me, I need to run Robot Framework set network proxy to access the web browse.